# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php since I've updated my Box Homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

So, I simply wanted to install the latest version of PHP GD to fix a problem of pixel.

Since then I've broken a lot of thing including mostly my vagrant/homestead box.

I remember having changed some permission and I think this is the main problem.

So do you have an idea of which folder shall have what kind of permission?

Answer (score 0):

From within your project dir

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Laravel framework file permission - Security

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-framework-file-permission-security

If that doesn't work try Destroying / rebuilding the homestead box.

Also, I would run:

```
artisan view:clear
artisan cache:clear
artisan config:clear
artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```